Figuring out how many times a specific word was mentioned each day over a certain period of time on X
I am trying to figure out a way to find out how many times a specific word preceded by the dollar sign (e.g., "$word") was mentioned each day over the last x months on Twitter (3 to 6 months).
(trying to do crypto ticker mention frequency comparison).
I tried writing my own code using the X developer API, the bulk of which is basically the following:
query = "$BTC"
end_date = datetime.now()
start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=3)  # Last 3 months

# Search tweets and aggregate daily counts
tweets = []
# for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=query, lang="en", since=start_date.date()).items():
#     tweets.append(status.created_at.date())

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=query, lang="en", count=10).items():
    tweets.append(status.created_at.date())


# Convert to DataFrame and count mentions per day
df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=["date"])
daily_mentions = df["date"].value_counts().sort_index()

which results in the following error message
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to a subset of X API V2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.x.com/en/portal/product

I understand the data I am trying to analyze is vast and I would need a paid subscription. But looking at the tiers, it's not clear to me which tier would let me analyze tickers that would be mentioned millions of times a day. (I doubt the Pro tier for X developer API would do the job)
I have tried tools such as Brand24 but as you can see in the image below, the tools I have tried clearly give you the wrong count (no way $btc was mentioned only 100 times and exactly 100 times every day this past month).

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how to go about doing it?
